# undefined symbol: _ZTI13my_plugin_api during Boost::DLL tutorial

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I have problem running the very first example of [Boost::DLL tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html). At some point I just copied code from the git repo to be sure I didn't do any mistake. Didn't help. Both executable and shared lib compile and link properly. However, I still get the same error when running the program:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
  what():  boost::dll::shared_library::load() failed (dlerror system message: ./libmy_plugin_sum.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI13my_plugin_api): Exec format error
Interrupt (memory dump)
```

The funny thing is I don't even have to try to import plugin to get this error...
**My question is what is happening and why?**

My abstract base (in file `my_plugin_api.hpp`):

```cpp
#include <boost/config.hpp>

#include <string>

class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE my_plugin_api {
public:
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual float calculate(float x, float y) = 0;

    virtual ~my_plugin_api();
};
```

My executable code (file `main.cpp`):

```cpp
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp> // for import_alias
#include <iostream>
#include "my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace dll = boost::dll;

boost::dll::fs::path get_path(char* str) {
    return boost::dll::fs::path(str);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    boost::dll::fs::path lib_path = get_path(argv[1]);             // argv[1] contains path to directory with our plugin library
    boost::shared_ptr<my_plugin_api> plugin;            // variable to hold a pointer to plugin variable
    std::cout << "Loading the plugin" << std::endl;
    
    auto multiply = dll::import<double(double, double)>(   //importing single function from library
        lib_path/"my_plugin_sum",
        "multiply",
        dll::load_mode::append_decorations
    );

    std::cout << multiply(1.5,1.5) << "\n";
}
```

Now, the important part, the library code (file `plugin.cpp`):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/config.hpp> // for BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp>

#include "my_plugin_api.hpp"

namespace my_namespace {

class my_plugin_sum : public my_plugin_api {
public:
    my_plugin_sum() {
        std::cout << "Constructing my_plugin_sum" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string name() const {
        return "sum";
    }

    float calculate(float x, float y) {
        return x + y;
    }
   
    ~my_plugin_sum() {
        std::cout << "Destructing my_plugin_sum ;o)" << std::endl;
    }
};

extern "C" BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT my_plugin_sum plugin;
my_plugin_sum plugin;

} // namespace my_namespace

extern "C" {
    BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT
    double multiply(double x, double y) { return x*y; }
}
```

**Additional info**:

- System version: `Ubuntu 20.10 (x64)`
- Compiler version: `g++ (Ubuntu 10.2.0-13ubuntu1) 10.2.0`
- Boost version: `1.75.0`
- Executable compiled with: `g++ main.cpp -o boost-plugin -ldl -lboost_filesystem`
- SO library compiled with: `g++ -shared -fPIC -fvisibility="hidden" -o libmy_plugin_sum.so plugin.cpp`

It is enough to remove the following two lines of library code:

```
extern "C" BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT my_plugin_sum plugin;
my_plugin_sum plugin;
```

and error disappears.

Part of result of `nm -C -D libmy_plugin_sum.so` (run on version that generates error):

```
0000000000011510 u guard variable for boost::system::detail::to_std_category(boost::system::error_category const&)::map_
000000000000a9dc W my_plugin_api::my_plugin_api()
000000000000a9dc W my_plugin_api::my_plugin_api()
                 U my_plugin_api::~my_plugin_api()
000000000000a87c W boost::system::system_error::~system_error()
.
.
.
00000000000ad12 W std::operator==(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > > const&, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<boost::system::error_category const* const, std::unique_ptr<boost::system::detail::std_category, std::default_delete<boost::system::detail::std_category> > > > const&)
                 U std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
                 U typeinfo for my_plugin_api
0000000000010ce0 V typeinfo for boost::system::system_error
0000000000010d40 V typeinfo for boost::system::error_category
```

List of objects of library version that doesn't cause any problems doesn't contain any `my_plugin_api` entry at all.

**EDIT:**

When looking at non-demangled symbols (`nm -D libmy_plugin_sum.so`) I get this:

```
0000000000011510 u _ZGVZN5boost6system6detail15to_std_categoryERKNS0_14error_categoryEE4map_
000000000000a9e2 W _ZN13my_plugin_apiC1Ev
000000000000a9e2 W _ZN13my_plugin_apiC2Ev
                 U _ZN13my_plugin_apiD2Ev
000000000000a882 W _ZN5boost6system12system_errorD0Ev

...

                 U _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTI13my_plugin_api
0000000000010ce0 V _ZTIN5boost6system12system_errorE

...

000000000000d2a0 V _ZTSN5boost6system6detail22generic_error_categoryE
                 U _ZTV13my_plugin_api
                 U _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE@@CXXABI_1.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is very simple. I was just blind :) .

In the abstract base class I declared destructor as virtual. That's ok. I knew it cannot be pure virtual function. **However if it's not pure virtual, it needs to be defined.**

So, in my abstract base class `my_plugin_api` instead of only declaring:

```
~my_plugin_api(); //declaration only!!!
```

I should have written definition:

```
~my_plugin_api() {} //definition!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit**: I didn't reproduce your literal message.
>
> To help you rule out any inconsistencies, I provided a step-for-step example repo, see below

Did you forget to add the library directory as the command line argument? I think the sample should have done some argument checking, like at least an assert:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    assert(argc > 1);
    boost::dll::fs::path lib_path(argv[1]);  // argv[1] contains path to directory with our plugin library
```

So, in my test, I just specify the current directory where the build output for the main application (`sotest`) and the library (`libmy_plugin_sum.so`) reside:

```
./sotest .
```

Or

```
./sotest "$PWD"
```

I've tested that it works both with the actual library name

```
lib_path / "libmy_plugin_sum.so",  // path to the library and library name
```

and the "linux convention for shard library naming":

```
lib_path / "my_plugin_sum",        // path to the library and library name
```

### UPDATE: Live Interactive Example

I decided to create an easy-to-reproduce sample: https://github.com/sehe/boost-dll-example

It contains

```
CMakeLists.txt
my_plugin_api.hpp
plugin_impl.cpp
test.cpp
```

The cpp/hpp are yours, the CMakeLists.txt is

```
project(stackoverflow)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS TRUE)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.61.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
LINK_LIBRARIES(Boost::filesystem dl)

ADD_LIBRARY(my_plugin_sum SHARED plugin_impl.cpp)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(sotest test.cpp)
```

And there are some VsCode settings:

```
./.devcontainer/devcontainer.json
./.devcontainer/Dockerfile
./.vscode/extensions.json
```

So that when you open the project in VsCode it's all automatic and will build the example in a container:

[image]

1. Clone the sample and open in vscode, e.g. with

   ```
   clone https://github.com/sehe/boost-dll-example
   code boost-dll-example
   ```
2. Install recommended extensions
3. Click to re-open in container (this may take a few minutes)
4. Locate CMake in the side-bar and click to "Build All Projects"
5. run `sotest` in the build folder, as above

Comment: Had to reduce the GIF quality. [Original mp4](http://stackoverflow-sehe.s3.amazonaws.com/a49d6eaa-478c-4168-9f5a-039080d1c1d2/out.mp4) in case it is easier to use/read.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it to double check. However, I'm properly invoking program. If I don't give command line parameter, program fails at `filesystem::path` construction, not at `dll:import` . Additionally, if I did not specify correct path, it wouldn't work with the lines `extern "C" BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT my_plugin_sum plugin;
my_plugin_sum plugin;` removed as it wouldn't be able to find library.

Comment: One more thing: I am using cmake and vscode :) . I removed it as it is another layer that could cause issues. I wanted to reproduce error with setup as simple as possible for easier debugging.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I don't use VsCode actually. Just thought it would be a nice way to package project + devcontainer. VsCode has it's sweet spot there

Comment: Ahh, I get it. Nevertheless: I think it's some problem with my setup/environment. I don't think boost shows not working code in their own tutorial. I'd like to understand why it's looking for mangled symbol (`_ZTI13my_plugin_api`) even if I'm not trying to import anything connected with it and why there is no such symbol in library...

Comment: I'm interested in finding that, but it's objectively impossible without the code/build files.

Comment: I did found the source of the problem :) . I my virtual base I declared virtual destructor but did not define it: `virtual ~my_plugin_api();` instead of `virtual ~my_plugin_api() {}` .